# Spoof .php as .png in .htaccess?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, dynamic

I created a dynamic image script in PHP but I want to show it as `.png`.

What is the `.htaccess` configuration to type `domain.com/image/image.png` and return the content of `domain.com/image/image.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your .htaccess file is placed at your web root, give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image/image\.png image/image.php [L]
```

Alternatively, you can name a directory "image.png" then place an index.php file in there thus: `image/image.png/index.php`.